# How does Rails turn STI models into their parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

EDIT: Rewriting entire question!

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ExternalProduct < Product
end
```

Rails has a way of turning ExternalProduct into Product, and that's the method I am looking for. So we want a true value in this assert:

```
assert ExternalProduct.some_method == Product
```

EDIT: I'm not looking how to assert this. I'm looking at how to turn ExternalProduct into Product.

EDIT2:

If this is my input:

```
:external_product
```

How can I turn it *WITHOUT* knowing of any subclassing or STI into the correct model, ie `Product`?

Comment: what version of Rails are you using? That code (minus the `get_true_model`) gives me `ExternalProduct`.

Comment: Great catch, thanks @sevenseacat, regarding your code edit.

Comment: Using ActiveRecord 3.2.12

Comment: @sevenseacat I want it to return "Product", will edit question to be more clear.

Comment: oh right, I misinterpreted what you were after, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExternalProduct.base_class` is the method you want.

Unlike `superclass` it'll actually give you the STI base class, so if if the hierarchy changes or you pass in a different object altogether, it'll still return the appropriate class.

See the source for `base_class`, and how its used by the STI internals [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L42).

Answer (score 3):

If you have an instance of `ExternalProduct` but you want it to be an instance of `Product`, you can do:

`@product = @external_product.becomes(Product)`

This is the equivalent of doing:

`@product = Product.new(@external_products.attributes)`

Maybe not the answer to your question, but possibly helpful to other people who come across this.

Comment: This should be `@external_product.becomes(Product)` (class name not string)

Comment: @kittyminky edit submitted, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the super class

```
>> ExternalProduct.superclass.name
>> "Product"
```

Here is a example for getting the super class.

```
>> e = ExternalProduct.first
>> ExternalProduct(id: 1, author_id: 1)
>> e.class
>> ExternalProduct(id: integer, author_id: integer
>> e.class.superclass
>> Product(id: integer, author_id: integer
>> e.class.superclass.name 
>> "Product"
```

Comment: `Product.superclass` equals `ActiveRecord::Base`, so you're suggestion I check whether or not its superclass is ActiveRecord::Base? Works for when using activerecord of course, which I have tagged the question is, but is not compatible with eg. Mongoid.